# Why heroes are physically stronger than average humans

Tags: my-hero-academia, tropes

In the world of My Hero Academia, the human society acquired Quirks.

So basically instead of having regular humans, we have humans with abilities.

With the exception of Power-Up quirks (like one for all...etc), why do humans/heroes/villains seem physically stronger?

I mean, they can go through walls and be smashed on the ground and still stand, with minor injuries, training can't make a human sustain such things..

In One Piece for example we know the world is filled with abnormally strong humans, but that's not the case in My Hero Academia, is it??

Bakugo standing up after Deku's power-up punch, even with 8% it can make holes in walls, why didn't it kill bakugo?

Comment: 8% was the maximum Deku could safely use at the time but that doesn't mean he hit Bakugo with that much power, even before Full Cowling he subconsciously limited the power he was using to not blow holes in people he hit.

Comment: you're focusing on the wrong part of the question. The people in this world are still normal. No one can sustain a hit not even 1%. Endeavor cannot go through a building and survive.. just because his body can generate fire..

Comment: I was addressing a particular point rather than providing an answer which is why it's a comment

Answer (score 4):

In a lot of anime, humans just have more durability than real-life humans. It's just a common trope. For example, *One Punch Man*, Saitama was repeatedly beaten down by Crablante before gaining any powers and survived. In *JoJo Battle Tendency*, Mark gets half of his head sheared off and is still able to talk for a while after. It's just a common thing in many anime that humans have higher-tier durability than their real life counterparts. I wouldn't pay much attention to this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Bakugo creates explosion from his body perhaps his body has adapted to deal with it. As such, other heros bodies have stengthened in order to deal with their quirks. Otherwise all heros would be impacted by their own quirks (eg Hizashi Yamada would be deaf by now).

We see this with (naturally quirkless) Deku when he needs to train his body to get used to his gifted quirk.

*tba - will add references when I can find a transcript.*

Answer (score 2):

Humans have the ability to physically train themselves to do things beyond their normal capacity.

Anime, shounen anime in particular, is known for over-exaggerating this well beyond what is possible in reality. In just about any shounen anime, a completely normal person can physically train themselves to the point where they can throw cars, survive a car being thrown at them, and other similar things that are well beyond what even a pheomenally trained human is capable of.

In the MHA world, heroes undergo intense physical training to be able to perform these feats. As such, they are capable of what you describe.